# Por que la sesion se me cierra al cerrar el navegador?

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de que cuando el usuario alla cerrado el navegador y no haya cerrado sesion al abrir el navegador este lo redirija a la pagina admin, pero automaticamente se cierra la sesion, alguna manera de que no se cierre al cerra completamente el navegador? ojo, si cierro la pestana la sesion sigue abierta, solo pasa cuando cierro el navegador completamente, aqui el codigo:

```
public static function login ($data) {
   
    $user = Clear::Clearvars($data["user"]);
    $pass = Clear::Clearvars($data["pass"]);
    $query = Model::login($user, $pass);
    if (is_array($query)) {
        self::start_session($query);
    }else {
        echo json_encode("0");
    }
}

public static function start_session($query) {
    setcookie("user",$query["user"],0);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user"] = $query["user"];
}

public static function verify_session_index() {
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
        ControllerView::renderview("admin_panel");
    }
}

Routes::set("index",function() {  
Login_admin::verify_session_index();
Controller::renderview('index');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente, estás seteando la cookie con expires=0. Eso hace que la sessión se cierre cuando cerrás el navegador.

Más en concreto: el browser usa cookies. Esas cookies tienen que tener una expiración (en algún momento se tienen que romper). Si le ponés una expiración a la cookie, entonces esa cookie va a perdurar en el navegador el tiempo que le hayas puesto, así lo cierres o lo dejes abierto.

Si le ponés expires=0, el navegador entiende que tiene que romper la cookie cuando se cierra.

Probá cambiando

```
setcookie("user",$query["user"],0);
```

Por otro tiempo de expiración, algo así como:

```
// Esto hace que se expire la cookie dentro de una hora
setcookie("user",$query["user"],time()+3600);
```

El tiempo de expiración depende de tu implementación. Yo te puse el ejemplo de una cookie que dura una hora.

Saludos!

Comment: no amigo, la cookie le puse 0, ya que asi le indico que solamente se va a eliminar cuando se cierre el navegador, eso es una prueba anterior que estaba haciendo, lo que quiero hacer es usar session para validar, pero como dije en la pregunta cuando cierro completamente el navegador este me cierra la sesion tambien y no puedo validar sus valores al volver a entrar